# Cannot get rid of first column i.e index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create a csv file from a dataframe that will look like

```
  time, price, vol
    178,     310,  10
    299,     510,  11
    378,     310,  11
```

my code gives me this

```
   time,  price,  vol
1   178       310,  10
2   299,     510,  11
3   378,     310,  11
```

how can I get rid of the first column i.e. Index 1,2,3

test code

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 4.5,10.6],[2, 8.8,12.7],[3, 2.2,13.8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['time', 'price','vol'])
df.set_index("time")
print( df)
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: You're not reassigning the result of `set_index()`, is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the file, use `index=False` flag, like this:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25450647)

Comment: @chevybow Actually it does in my opinion.